# jQuery .change() not working on textarea

Tags: jquery, forms, text, input, textarea

This is my first time asking on StackOverflow, but I'm currently stumped with some corporate code I'm creating. It will simply not accept the .change() or bind to keyup. I've haven't had a problem before with it, but it ceases to work for me today. Check out my code and see if you see anything that might cause a problem.

Sorry about the formatting, I'm new.

```
var currentContent = "null";
var customeri = "";
var optionsi = "";
var equipmenti = "";
var picturei = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#preview").hide();
    $("#previewPane").hide();
    $("#previewHeading").hide();
$(".uiFonts").click(function() {
    var clickedID = $(this).attr("id");
    if(clickedID !== null) {
        $("#main").hide();
        loadContent(clickedID);
    }
});

$("#Equipment").bind('change keyup', function() {
        equipmenti = $(this).val();
                    $("#preview").html('<br /><span class="reg">Customer Info<br /></span>'+customeri+'<br /><br /><span class="reg">Options<br /></span>'+optionsi+'<br /><br /><span class="reg">Equipment<br /></span>'+equipmenti+'<br /><br /><span class="reg">Picture:<br /></span><img src="'+picturei+'" />');
});
});
function loadContent(cID) {
$("#main").load(cID + ".html", function() {
    $("#main").slideDown(1500);
    $("#preview").fadeIn(1500);
    $("#previewPane").fadeIn(1500);
    $("#previewHeading").fadeIn(1500);
    currentContent = cID;
});
}
```

.html file containing textareas is as follows:

```
<p><span class="reg">Customer Info - Name, Address, Phone, Email</span><br />
<textarea name="Customer Info" class="textAreas inputs" id="Customer"></textarea>
<br />
<br />
<span class="reg">Trailer Options</span>
<br />
<textarea name="Options" class="inputs textAreas" id="Options"></textarea>
<br />
<br />
<span class="reg">Trailer Equipment</span>
<br />
<textarea name="Equipment" class="inputs textAreas" id="Equipment"></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<span class="reg">Picture URL</span></p>
<input type="text" id="picture" class="inputs"></input>
```

And I have tried binding them in general like:

```
$(".inputs").change(function() {
    customeri = $("#Customer").val();
    optionsi = $("#Options").val();
    //etc
```

Comment: Welcome...!  For clarity, what are you wanting this `change()` to do?

Comment: Welcome, if you want people to help you out, I suggest you trim your code to what does not work and - even better - prepare a http://jsfiddle.net/ to show your example and what you mean by not working.

Comment: `$("#Equipment").bind("change keyup")` uses the variables `equipmenti` and `optionsi`, but never sets them. And the `change` function at the bottom sets the variables, but doesn't do anything with them. You need a handler that does both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loading an external .html file, jquery cannot access it regularly and apply actions to it. This problem arises because within the trigger $(document).ready it finds no link to the id found within the .html until it is loaded, and it is too late for it to find it if you call an external .html after the document is ready.

A workaround is to contain the .change within a separate jquery function, or just load the .html before the document is finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

Working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2JST2/3/). To confirm, I added  `<div id='test'/>` , `$("#Equipment").bind('change keyup', function(e) { $('#test').append(e.type);` and get keyup and change as expected.

**UPDATE**  I think your problem is elsewhere, because the events are both firing.  (You do know that change only fires after leaving the `textarea` with a different value?)

Comment: I seriously cannot get this to work. I mean, you have all my code. I've made it alot more generally and concise and it still will not work.
**EDIT:**
I think I've logically figured out the problem, it seems to me that when loading an externally .html, it calls the function when the document is ready, but the class and ids are not loaded until the loadContent() is called, therefore rendering it not accessible and ignores the .bind(). Let me compile it into a separate div and see how it goes. I will update you guys!

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of what was going on.